# Rails asset pipelines resolves completely wrong path (and what's the absolute file path doing there?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, assets

When using Rails `asset_path` helper in development mode to include an image, I'm seeing Rails resolve the asset to a URL that includes the absolute path of the image on filesystem (really, I'm serious).

Let's start with the css.erb file:

```
body {
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path "cork.bg.gif" %>);
}
```

The path returned from the helper looks fine in the compiled CSS...

```
body {
  background: url(/assets/cork.bg.gif);
}
```

... but when the browser requests /assets/cork.bg.gif, that's when all hell breaks loose. Take this example (screenshot of the real thing):

[image: WTF is this?]

What's more, the logs show that the middleware is actually fielding **two requests**:

```
Started GET "/assets/cork.bg.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-31 18:52:39 -0400
Served asset /cork.bg.gif - 200 OK (0ms)

Started GET "/var/www/corkboard.me/app/assets/images/cork.bg.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-31 18:52:39 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/var/www/corkboard.me/app/assets/images/cork.bg.gif"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.6.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
  unicorn (4.6.2) bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'


  Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

I don't understand what's going on and solving the issue is very frustrating. It's one request from the browser. What could be adding that absolute file path?

Here's my application.rb and development.rb config files. Please help. Whoever gives me the answer that fixes this can have a free year's subscription to NoteApp (https://noteapp.com)

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

SITE_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("config/config.yml")[Rails.env]

module Corkboard
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    # config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :xdr_data]

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.1'
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
Corkboard::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Set header for nginx to handle large uploads.
  # e.g. http://thedataasylum.com/articles/how-rails-nginx-x-accel-redirect-work-together.html
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = false

  config.serve_static_assets = true
end
```

**Edit:** Added nginx configuration.

```
worker_processes 1;
user nobody nogroup;

pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/www/corkboard.me/log/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  # Set this to on if you have more than 1 working processes
  # This will allow only one child to watch the pollset and accept
  # a connection to a socket
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/www/corkboard.me/log/nginx.access.log combined;

  # This tells Nginx to ignore the contents of a file it is sending
  # and uses the kernel sendfile instead
  sendfile on;

  # Set this to on if you have sendfile on
  # It will prepend the HTTP response headers before
  # calling sendfile()
  tcp_nopush on;

  # This disables the "Nagle buffering algorithm" (Nginx Docs)
  # Good for websites that send a lot of small requests that
  # don't need a response
  tcp_nodelay off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css
             text/comma-separated-values
             text/javascript application/x-javascript
             application/atom+xml;

  upstream unicorn_server {
    # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
    server unix:/var/www/corkboard.me/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
    fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/file.key;

    server_name hello.corkboard.me;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/file.key; 

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name .corkboard.me;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    rewrite ^ https://noteapp.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.noteapp.com;

    ssl_certificate      /path/to/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/file.key;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    rewrite ^ https://noteapp.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/file.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/file.key;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name noteapp.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Location of our static files
    root /var/www/corkboard.me/public;

    location / {
      set $https_val "";

      if ($server_port = 443) {
        set $https_val "https";
      }

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO $https_val;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      # If you don't find the filename in the static files
      # Then request it from the unicorn server
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
        break;
      }
    }

    error_page 502 503 /maintenance.html;
    error_page 500 504 /500.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it looks as though I should have read the asset pipeline docs more thoroughly. I missed this big red box related to X-Sendfile headers:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#x-sendfile-headers

And my apologies. The headers aren't included in the nginx configuration above because of a bad copy/paste job.